# What is the word for a step that is too small?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What word would you use to descripe a step of a process that should be combined with another step because it is too small to be its 'own' step?

Example.

1. Create a copy of the file.
2. Rename the file.
3. Make the file name "hello.txt".
4. Open the file.. blah blah blah...

You could consider step 2 and 3 to be a single step. What would you describe step 3 as, considering it is a miniscule step and could be combined with 2?

Kind of a bad example... I'll try to think of another if I can.

Hopefully you understand what I mean by this.

Comment: A half-step maybe?

Comment: Well, 2 and 3 really **are** a single step - all you've done is state it in different words. In a more meaningful example, you could perhaps say *2: Rename the file. 2a: Right-click on the filename. 2b: Left-click on "Rename". 2c: Type the new name "hello.txt". 2d: Press the <return> key.* That would make it clear you are enumerating **sub-tasks / sub-steps**.

Comment: How would I explain to somebody that the step is too small?  Maybe there isn't a word for it and I am going crazy for no reason, but it seems like I should be able to say: "That step is xyz" or "That is a xyz step"

Comment: That step is too pedantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to describe the fact that they've been broken up too much by saying they're *too granular*.

You could point out the unnecessary wordiness by saying the steps are *too verbose*.

Personally I would just point out that step 2 is *incomplete* because it doesn't contain enough information for the person to execute it.  They need to know what to call the file in order to successfully execute the step.

Comment: I like granular. I guess a word for this specific purpose doesn't exist, but that sounds nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would call 3 a **sub-step** of 2, but really they could co-exist:

1. Create a copy of the file
2. **Save the copy as "Hello.txt"**
3. Open the file... blah

Answer (score 2):

It's just a metaphor, and probably best reserved for a scientific audience, but I've heard people use the word *subatomic* to express the concept you describe.  In other words:

> *I'd combine Steps 2 and 3; Step 3 seems rather **subatomic**.*

I consulted several online dictionaries, and found these listed as definitions and synonyms for atomic: *immeasurably small*, *minute*, *infinitesimal*.

Computer scientists have latched onto this adjective when describing process steps:

**atomic operation** (computer science):
*An operation that cannot be broken up into smaller parts; **atomic** implies indivisibility and irreducibility*.

Answer (score 1):

Extra steps that are *too fine-grained* may be considered *redundant*, or perhaps *[insignificant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insignificant)* ("not important, consequential, or having a noticeable effect"), *[inconsequential](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inconsequential)*, or *[negligible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negligible)* ("able to be ignored or excluded from consideration; too small or unimportant to be of concern").  More figuratively, you could refer to them as *[small fry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/small_fry)* ("things of relatively little consequence, importance, or value"), *[frivolous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frivolous)* ("of little weight or importance; not worth notice; slight"), an *[eyeblink](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eyeblink)*, or *[homeopathic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homeopathic)*.

Answer (score 0):

In physics, *quantum* is the "minimum amount of a physical quantity which can exist" (OED), so one possibility might be to call the step a "sub-quantum" step.

Applying the same rationale, another possibility is "sub-incremental".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word **exiguous**

> very small in size or amount.